# Searching multiple patterns with single LIKE clause

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

How could I achieve something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1
WHERE Column_A CONTAINS ("AB" OR "BE" OR "DE");
```

I have more than 15 values to put in the contains() so it would be tedious to do it by hand (I mean "where A contains "AB" OR A contains "BE" etc.)

Thanks for any tips,

Comment: What do you mean by "CONTAINS"?  Do you mean `=`?

Comment: I'm using SAS at work and it uses CONTAINS for LIKE "%word%". I learnt that with this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1
WHERE Column_A in ('AB','BE','DE');
```

This will output all rows in Table_1 where Column_A have any value specified in IN CLAUSE. So it basically works as OR.

**Note:** This will work if you are searching 'AB' as a whole. If you want all rows having 'AB' or 'BE' anywhere in the column value string then you have to use like clause like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1
WHERE Column_A like '%AB%' OR Column_A like '%BE%' OR Column_A like '%DE%';
```

**Update** : You could use below one as well, this serves your purpose and you don't have to write LIKE Clause 15-20 times.

```
Create table employee (name varchar(200))
Insert into employee values('ABC')
Insert into employee values('DEF')
Insert into employee values('BCD')
Insert into employee values('EFG')
Insert into employee values('ADC')

SELECT
  distinct name
FROM
  (
    VALUES
      ('%A%'),
      ('%D%')
  ) AS v (pattern)
  CROSS APPLY
  (  -- your query
    SELECT * 
    FROM       employee
    WHERE      name like v.pattern
  ) AS x
```

Comment: in() looks for equals values. Here I want just containg values. So if A = "RABI", it's ok because it contains "AB".

Comment: I have edited my post. You need to use Like clause as shown in second query.

Comment: @lekythos, Check my latest update. It will solve your purpose.

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` is a Microsoft SQL Server extension. It doesn't exist in SAS Proc SQL (or any other SQL dialect that I'm aware of).